# mutliple definition of preproccessor # value

Tags: c++, macros, dsl

I'm creating a project where I try to make a new language making macros.

The thing is that a macro named `X` is used for 2 different usages:

1. to close a function call with parethesis like `);}`, where `;` ends the line of code, and `}` closes the block of code,
2. and sometimes I want just to `;}`.

In conclusion, I need to make a smart trick where sometimes the preproccessor line after line understands `X` needs to be either `);}` or `;}`.

Can I somehow do it with `if else` statement, or somehow to strip the `if` needed?

I tried some implementation of conditional value where `, ( condition ? state1 : state2 )` but this was translated as as string from the preproccesor.

Also, I tried from other macros each time they called to `#undef X` and redefine `X` according what to do in my line, etc.

Comment: You need to come up with a different approach that doesn't require context-dependent replacement.

Comment: Can you simply define (and use) two different macros?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preprocessor is not sufficiently complex to allow for things like context-dependent replacement! The preprocessor understands **nothing** about C++ syntax, it literally runs before the C++ parser. But you would need your preprocessor to "understand" where you need a closing symbol, and it can't do that.

And looking at the way it's standardized, I think that's intentional.

In short: you can't build a DSL that requires this. In all honestly, modern C++ is flexible enough that you can build a DSL within C++ itself, but you'd of course still be bound by C++'s general syntax. If you need something else, I'd say that C++ & the standard preprocessor probably *is not the tool you need*.

That being said, if you're content with putting your DSL into C++ string literals like `"…"`, then you can do a compile-time DSL using `constexpr` parsing – which is exactly what [@vitaut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/471164/vitaut)'s [`{fmt}`](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) implements a string formatting DSL within C++.